# Python child initlisation conventions - using multiple parents to calculate properties

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization

I'm interested in using two parent instances to generate results in a child class. The commonality here is that all the class methods/attributes can be defined as some calculation or selection of the parents.

I'm worried the example below may be far from convention, where a child class usually calls the `__init__()` function of the parent using `super`. Here, `ChildClass` seemingly doesn't need to call `super.__init__()` as it would derive all of it's attributes from pointers to `ParentClass` instances `p1` or `p2`.

Is this bad practice? If there's any conventions for this sort of usage it would be awesome to know.

```
class ParentClass():
   def __init__(self,a,b,c):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
      self.c = c
      #... perform some other data initalisation ...

   def data_method1(self):
      #....

   # additional methods....

   def data_methodN():
      #....

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
   def __init__(self,p1,p2):
      self.p1 = p1
      self.p2 = p2
      
      self.a = p1.a #object pointers
      self.b = p2.b
      #... perform some other data initialisation ...

      # no super().__init__() needed??
   
   @property
   def c(self):
      """Property calculated from both parent instance objects"""
      return (self.p1.c + self.p2.c)/2

   #data_method1 runs as usual and doesn't need override.

   @override
   def data_methodN():
      #.... some method I want to override that needs 
      #.... different functionality using p1 and p2

   # additional methods....
```

Apologies if this is already a question (I assumed it would be), but can't find anything similar using the typical keywords haha.

Comment: Why not call `super().__init__(p1.a, p2.b)`?

Comment: I recommend to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Is `ChildClass` a meaningful substitute for a `ParentClass`? Are there places that expect a `ParentClass` where you'd meaningfully pass a `ChildClass` instead?

Comment: @Brian61354270 It would be useful for a notebook user to have direct pointers to the parent objects, particularly when working with datasets. The other complexity is the depth of variables in the initialization requirement for `ParentClass`, which would be non-meaningful to untangle from the two parent instances to pass to the constructor (I posted a very simple example...)

@MichaelButscher Thanks I think this might be what I need to have a look at.